# Scroll method - Javascript - Combine methods?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some `div`s called `column` in my HTML.

I want to be able to `console.log` a message whenever I start to scroll down a page and hit the first `div class="column"`.

I want to also be able to log a different message halfway through the `column` divs and then finally the last message at the end.

**Question**

Currently, I'm just seeing if it'll work by hitting the first div.

Would I be able to chain methods together, namely, `onscroll and getElementByClassNames`?

Basically, as I'm scrolling from the top of my page to where it hits the first `div class="column"`, I want to log something, then in the middle, then at the bottom of the page.

I cannot use `IntersectionObserver`

**INSTRUCTIONS**

You will notice on this page are a bunch of `div`s with the class `column`. In this task,
you are to write javascript code that will print events to the console whenever the top of
one of these `column`s becomes visible on the screen, when the `column` becomes more than 
50% visible on the screen, and when the `column` becomes completely visible on the screen.
Messages that are printed to the console should look like:

"Column with id:`id-10` started to become visible on the page."

"Column with id:`id-50` is now more than 50% visible on the page."

"Column with id:`id-40` is now fully visible on the page."

Once a column is visible on the screen all 3 events should have fired. All events for a
given column should fire once, and fire once only.

**HTML + JS**

```js
window.onscroll = () => {
  {myFunction()};
}

const myFunction = () => {
  if (window.onscroll.getElementsByClassName === "column") {
    console.log('test');
  } else {
    console.log('no');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ui container">
  <div class="ui grid">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ui text container">
  <h3 class="first">Text Container</h3>
  <p>Sometimes you just need to put a single column of centered text on a page. A <code>text container</code> is a special type of container optimized for a single flowing column of text, like this instructions on this page.
  </p>
  <p>Text containers <b>do not need to use grids</b> and help simplify basic page layouts.</p>
</div>

<div class="ui text container">
  <div class="ui one column grid">
    <div class="column"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="ui text container">

  <h1 class="ui dividing header">Grid Content</h1>

  <h3 class="first">Column Flow</h3>
  <p>A grid does not necessarily need to specify rows. If you include <code>columns</code> as direct child of <code>ui grid</code> content will automatically flow to the next row when all the grid columns are taken in the current row</b>.</p>

  <div class="ui grid">
    <div class="four wide column"></div>
    <div class="four wide column"></div>
    <div class="four wide column"></div>
    <div class="four wide column"></div>
    <div class="four wide column"></div>
    <div class="four wide column"></div>
    <div class="four wide column"></div>
    <div class="four wide column"></div>
  </div>

  <h3>Clearing Rows</h3>
  <p>Adding row wrappers allow you to manually specify you want a new row to begin.</p>

  <div class="ui three column grid">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column"></div>
      <div class="column"></div>
      <div class="column"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h3>Specifying Row Width</h3>
  <p>Specifying a grid column count will divide columns into rows of predetermined column count. Additional columns will automatically flow to the next row.</p>
  <div class="ui three column grid">
    <div class="column">column</div>
    <div class="column">column</div>
    <div class="column">column</div>
    <div class="column">column</div>
    <div class="column">column</div>
    <div class="column">column</div>
  </div>

  <h3>Specifying Column Width</h3>
  <p>You can also specify column widths for each column individually</p>
  <div class="ui three column grid">
    <div class="four wide column">four wide column</div>
    <div class="eight wide column">eight wide column</div>
    <div class="four wide column">four wide column</div>
  </div>

  <h3>Special Variations</h3>
  <p>Some special variations that format grids like tables require you to specify rows. For example a <code>divided grid</code> or a <code>celled grid</code> requires row wrappers.</p>

  <div class="ui horizontal section divider">Celled Grid</div>
  <div class="ui celled grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ui horizontal section divider">Internally Celled Grid</div>

  <div class="ui internally celled grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="ui horizontal section divider">Divided Grid</div>

  <div class="ui divided grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ui horizontal section divider">Vertically Divided Grid</div>

  <div class="ui vertically divided grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
      <div class="four wide column"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h1 class="ui dividing header">Adjusting Grids</h1>


  <h3 class="first">Centering Content</h3>
  <p>If a row does not take up all sixteen grid columns, you can use a <code>ui centered grid</code>, <code>centered row</code>, or <code>centered column</code> to center the column contents inside the grid.
  </p>
  <div class="ui two column centered grid">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="four column centered row">
      <div class="column"></div>
      <div class="column"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h3>Floating Rows</h3>
  <p>Since Semantic UI's grid is based on flex box, a <code>left floated</code> item should come first, and a <code>right floated</code> item last in its row.</p>

  <div class="ui grid">
    <div class="left floated six wide column">
      <div class="ui segment">
        Left floated
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right floated six wide column">
      <div class="ui segment">
        Right floated
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <h3>Text Alignment</h3>
  <p>You can specify text alignment using alignment variations on a grid, row, or column level.</p>

  <div class="ui grid">
    <div class="right aligned eight wide column">
      right aligned column
    </div>
    <div class="left aligned eight wide column">
      left aligned column
    </div>
    <div class="center aligned two column row">
      <div class="column">
        center aligned row
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        center aligned row
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sixteen wide right aligned column">
      right aligned column
    </div>
  </div>

  <h3>Vertical Alignment</h3>
  <p>You can specify vertical alignment on a grid, row, or column level.</p>
  <div class="ui middle aligned four column centered grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <img class="ui wireframe image" src="wireframe.png">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img class="ui wireframe image" src="wireframe.png">
        <img class="ui wireframe image" src="wireframe.png">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img class="ui wireframe image" src="wireframe.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h3>Equal Width Columns</h3>
  <p>Specifying an <code>equal width grid</code> will automatically determine column sizes to fit evenly inside one row</p>
  <div class="ui equal width grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">column</div>
      <div class="column">column</div>
      <div class="column">column</div>
      <div class="column">column</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">column</div>
      <div class="column">column</div>
      <div class="column">column</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <h1>Responsive Patterns</h1>

  <h3 class="first">Doubling</h3>
  <p>You can set columns to double in width at each device jump</p>
  <div class="ui five column doubling grid">
    <div class="column">column</div>
    <div class="column">column</div>
    <div class="column">column</div>
    <div class="column">column</div>
    <div class="column">column</div>
  </div>

  <h3>Stackable</h3>
  <p>You can set columns to stack on mobile</p>
  <div class="ui three column stackable grid">
    <div class="column">column</div>
    <div class="column">column</div>
    <div class="column">column</div>
  </div>

  <h3>Responsive Width Adjustments</h3>
  <p>You can specify columns to appear at different widths on different screens</p>

  <div class="ui grid">
    <div class="eight wide mobile six wide tablet four wide computer column"></div>
    <div class="eight wide mobile six wide tablet four wide computer column"></div>
    <div class="eight wide mobile six wide tablet four wide computer column"></div>
    <div class="eight wide mobile six wide tablet four wide computer column"></div>
    <div class="eight wide mobile six wide tablet four wide computer column"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui grid">
    <div class="four wide two wide large screen one wide widescreen column"></div>
    <div class="four wide two wide large screen one wide widescreen column"></div>
    <div class="four wide two wide large screen one wide widescreen column"></div>
    <div class="four wide two wide large screen one wide widescreen column"></div>
  </div>

  <h3>Specifying Device Visibility</h3>
  <p>You can specify columns to appear only a particular screen</p>
  <div class="ui grid">
    <div class="two column computer only row">
      <div class="ten wide column">ten wide column computer only</div>
      <div class="six wide column">six wide column computer only</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sixteen wide mobile only column">sixteen wide column mobile only</div>
    <div class="three column computer only row">
      <div class="column">computer only row</div>
      <div class="column">computer only row</div>
      <div class="column">computer only row</div>
    </div>
    <div class="two column mobile only row">
      <div class="column">mobile only column</div>
      <div class="column">mobile only column</div>
    </div>
    <div class="two column row">
      <div class="column">column</div>
      <div class="column">column</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver interface. Doing so allows us to be notified when an event of interest occurs, rather than some other event (scrolling) from which we then try to see if the event we're concerned with (element becoming visible) is actually happening.

```js
"use strict";
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag)}
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
function qsa(sel,par=document){return par.querySelectorAll(sel)}

window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt)
{
 let potentialTargets = qsa('.column');
 let tgt1 = potentialTargets[0];
 let tgt2 = potentialTargets[(potentialTargets.length-1)/2];
 let tgt3 = potentialTargets[potentialTargets.length-1];
 
 let targets = [tgt1, tgt2, tgt3];

 var intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver( intObvCb );

 // start observing
 targets.forEach( function(tgt){ intersectionObserver.observe(tgt); } );

 function intObvCb(entries) 
 {
  // if intersection ratio is 0, the target is out of view
  // and we do not need to do anything
  if (entries[0].intersectionRatio <= 0) 
   return;
 
  // determine which of the targets triggered the function and respond
  console.log( targets.indexOf(entries[0].target) );
 }
}
```

```html
    <div class="ui container">
      <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui text container">
      <h3 class="first">Text Container</h3>
      <p>Sometimes you just need to put a single column of centered text on a page. A <code>text container</code> is a special type of container optimized for a single flowing column of text, like this instructions on this page.
      </p>
      <p>Text containers <b>do not need to use grids</b> and help simplify basic page layouts.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ui text container">
      <div class="ui one column grid">
        <div class="column"></div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="ui text container">

      <h1 class="ui dividing header">Grid Content</h1>

      <h3 class="first">Column Flow</h3>
      <p>A grid does not necessarily need to specify rows. If you include <code>columns</code> as direct child of <code>ui grid</code> content will automatically flow to the next row when all the grid columns are taken in the current row</b>.</p>

      <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="four wide column"></div>
        <div class="four wide column"></div>
        <div class="four wide column"></div>
        <div class="four wide column"></div>
        <div class="four wide column"></div>
        <div class="four wide column"></div>
        <div class="four wide column"></div>
        <div class="four wide column"></div>
      </div>

      <h3>Clearing Rows</h3>
      <p>Adding row wrappers allow you to manually specify you want a new row to begin.</p>

      <div class="ui three column grid">
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column"></div>
          <div class="column"></div>
          <div class="column"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <h3>Specifying Row Width</h3>
      <p>Specifying a grid column count will divide columns into rows of predetermined column count. Additional columns will automatically flow to the next row.</p>
      <div class="ui three column grid">
        <div class="column">column</div>
        <div class="column">column</div>
        <div class="column">column</div>
        <div class="column">column</div>
        <div class="column">column</div>
        <div class="column">column</div>
      </div>

      <h3>Specifying Column Width</h3>
      <p>You can also specify column widths for each column individually</p>
      <div class="ui three column grid">
        <div class="four wide column">four wide column</div>
        <div class="eight wide column">eight wide column</div>
        <div class="four wide column">four wide column</div>
      </div>

      <h3>Special Variations</h3>
      <p>Some special variations that format grids like tables require you to specify rows. For example a <code>divided grid</code> or a <code>celled grid</code> requires row wrappers.</p>

      <div class="ui horizontal section divider">Celled Grid</div>
      <div class="ui celled grid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ui horizontal section divider">Internally Celled Grid</div>

      <div class="ui internally celled grid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="ui horizontal section divider">Divided Grid</div>

      <div class="ui divided grid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ui horizontal section divider">Vertically Divided Grid</div>

      <div class="ui vertically divided grid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
          <div class="four wide column"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <h1 class="ui dividing header">Adjusting Grids</h1>


      <h3 class="first">Centering Content</h3>
      <p>If a row does not take up all sixteen grid columns, you can use a <code>ui centered grid</code>, <code>centered row</code>, or <code>centered column</code> to center the column contents inside the grid.
      </p>
      <div class="ui two column centered grid">
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="four column centered row">
          <div class="column"></div>
          <div class="column"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <h3>Floating Rows</h3>
      <p>Since Semantic UI's grid is based on flex box, a <code>left floated</code> item should come first, and a <code>right floated</code> item last in its row.</p>

      <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="left floated six wide column">
          <div class="ui segment">
            Left floated
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right floated six wide column">
          <div class="ui segment">
            Right floated
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <h3>Text Alignment</h3>
      <p>You can specify text alignment using alignment variations on a grid, row, or column level.</p>

      <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="right aligned eight wide column">
          right aligned column
        </div>
        <div class="left aligned eight wide column">
          left aligned column
        </div>
        <div class="center aligned two column row">
          <div class="column">
            center aligned row
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            center aligned row
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sixteen wide right aligned column">
          right aligned column
        </div>
      </div>

      <h3>Vertical Alignment</h3>
      <p>You can specify vertical alignment on a grid, row, or column level.</p>
      <div class="ui middle aligned four column centered grid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <img class="ui wireframe image" src="wireframe.png">
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <img class="ui wireframe image" src="wireframe.png">
            <img class="ui wireframe image" src="wireframe.png">
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <img class="ui wireframe image" src="wireframe.png">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <h3>Equal Width Columns</h3>
      <p>Specifying an <code>equal width grid</code> will automatically determine column sizes to fit evenly inside one row</p>
      <div class="ui equal width grid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">column</div>
          <div class="column">column</div>
          <div class="column">column</div>
          <div class="column">column</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">column</div>
          <div class="column">column</div>
          <div class="column">column</div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <h1>Responsive Patterns</h1>

      <h3 class="first">Doubling</h3>
      <p>You can set columns to double in width at each device jump</p>
      <div class="ui five column doubling grid">
        <div class="column">column</div>
        <div class="column">column</div>
        <div class="column">column</div>
        <div class="column">column</div>
        <div class="column">column</div>
      </div>

      <h3>Stackable</h3>
      <p>You can set columns to stack on mobile</p>
      <div class="ui three column stackable grid">
        <div class="column">column</div>
        <div class="column">column</div>
        <div class="column">column</div>
      </div>

      <h3>Responsive Width Adjustments</h3>
      <p>You can specify columns to appear at different widths on different screens</p>

      <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="eight wide mobile six wide tablet four wide computer column"></div>
        <div class="eight wide mobile six wide tablet four wide computer column"></div>
        <div class="eight wide mobile six wide tablet four wide computer column"></div>
        <div class="eight wide mobile six wide tablet four wide computer column"></div>
        <div class="eight wide mobile six wide tablet four wide computer column"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="four wide two wide large screen one wide widescreen column"></div>
        <div class="four wide two wide large screen one wide widescreen column"></div>
        <div class="four wide two wide large screen one wide widescreen column"></div>
        <div class="four wide two wide large screen one wide widescreen column"></div>
      </div>

      <h3>Specifying Device Visibility</h3>
      <p>You can specify columns to appear only a particular screen</p>
      <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="two column computer only row">
          <div class="ten wide column">ten wide column computer only</div>
          <div class="six wide column">six wide column computer only</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sixteen wide mobile only column">sixteen wide column mobile only</div>
        <div class="three column computer only row">
          <div class="column">computer only row</div>
          <div class="column">computer only row</div>
          <div class="column">computer only row</div>
        </div>
        <div class="two column mobile only row">
          <div class="column">mobile only column</div>
          <div class="column">mobile only column</div>
        </div>
        <div class="two column row">
          <div class="column">column</div>
          <div class="column">column</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**EDIT**
The question has since been edited, to remove the ability to use the interface designed for the task - `IntersectionObserver`

You'll just need to maintain an array that's updated each time a scroll event is fired. Check the current state of the element on the page with the state recorded in your array and, you'll get the ability to see which element has become or stopped being visible.

These are an alternative to `onLoaded`

```
function onLoaded2(evt)
{
    let potentialTargets = qsa('.column');
    let tgt1 = potentialTargets[0];
    let tgt2 = potentialTargets[(potentialTargets.length-1)/2];
    let tgt3 = potentialTargets[potentialTargets.length-1];

    let targets = [tgt1, tgt2, tgt3];

    // create and initialize an array holding each item's visible state
    // this will be used to compare the current state of visibility with the state
    // last time it was inspected. If they're the same, nothing's happened.
    // If the last state and current state are different, you know which element just
    // entered or exited the viewport.
    let visibleStates = [];
    targets.forEach( function(tgt, idx, arr){ visibleStates[idx] = isScrolledIntoView(tgt); } );

    console.log(visibleStates);

    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll, false);

    function onScroll(evt)
    {
        targets.forEach( 
            function(tgt,idx)
            {
                let isVisible = isScrolledIntoView(tgt);
                if (visibleStates[idx] != isVisible)
                    console.log(`element index ${idx} is now ${isVisible ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}`);
                visibleStates[idx] = isVisible;
            }
        );
    }
}


function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = window.scrollY;
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + window.innerHeight;

    var elemTop = elem.offsetTop;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + elem.offsetHeight;

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

Comment: appreciate the answer, I forgot to add that the instructions say not to use `IntersectionObserver`.

Comment: yeah, otherwise your answer makes sense

Comment: can you chain a scroll method to a getElementByClassNames?

Comment: You're not scrolling the individual elements - only the window. These is no utility in such a connection. I've added to my solution another means of achieving the desired result.

Comment: ah appreciate it, is `use strict` a necessity?

Comment: Welcome. Strictly speaking (ha-ha) you don't, but it is a good practise to be in the habit of, since it will help you catch errors sooner and write better code.

Comment: ah gotcha, im gonna post the rest of the instructions, cause i was going to take it step by step. What does it mean by the `top of the one of these columns`? Just as soon as the first div we're looking shows up?

Comment: Have a look at the function in my answer, `isScrolledIntoView` - notice how it checks to see if both the top and bottom are visible? Well, I'd say if the top was, but the bottom wasn't, that would be indicative of "top of one of these columns". If the top and bottom are visible, then you've got the third situation - fully visible on the page. This then leaves you with the last situation - over 50% visible. You'll need to find out how tall the element is and then how much of it is visible. good luck.

Comment: how tall the element is??

Comment: Yes. Which dimension is usually large if someone is said to be tall? Google search "define: tall"

Comment: im not sure, illl check it out, but what does height have to do with it? I'm taking the instructions as, if half of the divs show up on the page, then log a message

Comment: Also, I see you defined a `byId` function, but it's not used? Am I missing something?

Comment: Height is important, since you need to know what it is before you can asses whether or not 50% or more of the element is visible. Remember your second message "Column with id:id-50 is now more than 50% visible on the page." That's why element height is important - you can't assess attainment of the 50% requirement if you dont know how big it is! 

Nope, you're not missing something - I've either typed it in on auto-pilot or left it in my blank template file. Almost always want `document.getElementById` and `document.querySelectorAll`, hence the 2 short-cut functions.

Comment: hm icic, then ill have to figure this out. Not sure why it's confusing me. My thinking is that I have all these `divs` and if I total them up and divide in half, that's the div I want to have log a message on, the one in the middle

Comment: know of a quick way to get the page to be responsive no matter the size of the screen?

Comment: @mph85 - think about it for 1/2 a second (then stop, since I already solved that problem!) First, Middle and Last element of an array... (tgt1, tgt2, tgt3).

Responsive? Nah mate, sorry. That question is entirely too open-ended. I generally find making something happen or work to be fairly trivial. The bit I find really difficult is deciding *what* to make happen or work. As such, I'd have to have formulated a view in my mind as to how I'd like the page's appearance to change with resolution, before setting about making that happen. Time to do some more research. I'm done here - you'll be ok

Comment: for sure, appreciate all the help.